# Merge border of Items contained in an ListBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a ListBox with UniformGrid as its ItemsPanel. Basically, I wan't to show Items as Rectangles with border. I used UniformGrid as ItemsPanel, where I can control the number of rows and columns displayed through bindings.

I am setting border for each item using the ItemContainerStyle of ListBox. I can specify the BorderThickness and it does appear around all items in the List. The issue is that the borders don't merge for adjacent items giving a **"double border"** for adjacent items. How do I control the border of each item such that each one has a unique thickness even though it may have adjacent items.

Here is the scaled down code

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource RelayDispositionStyle}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" gs:DragDropExtension.ScrollOnDragDrop="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle}"
                     >
</ListBox>

<Style x:Key="RelayDispositionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>

    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ElementName=Racks, Path=SelectedItem.NoOfRows}" 
                                     Columns="{Binding ElementName=Racks, Path=SelectedItem.GroupsPerRow}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="RelayDispositionItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: May be, `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>` for items and set left and top border for whole listbox?

Comment: With Value="0,0,1,1", the adjacent cells have correct border thickness, but the cells in the top row loose their upper border, and the cells in the leftmost column loose their left border!

Comment: Try wrap UniformGrid with Border, which `BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"`.

Comment: I tried that, but the ItemsPanelTemplate does not allow that. It only accepts elements that are Panels.

Comment: Change margin for grid: `<UniformGrid Margin="1,11,0,0">`. Leave border for items: `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>`. Add negative margin for items: `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0"/>`.

Comment: Superb, I have been trying to fix this issue for long and its so easily fixed. Can you post the comment as answer, so that I can mark it as correct. It can help someone else. Thanks

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Yes I get that. Will be careful in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick with negative margins:
1. Set grid margins as `<UniformGrid Margin="1,11,0,0">`. Then it has additional 1px at left and top, which is item border thickness.
2. Set item margins as `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0"/>`. Items which is more right or more down will coincide with their neighbours. The leftmost and topmost items fill 1px of grid margin.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with a TabControl/TabItem, but the problem is the same. I solve it by retemplating the TabItem (in your case it would be the ListBoxItem) adding a trigger to alter the borders (notice the first ControlTemplateTrigger).

To make it work, you have to make your first item somehow diffrent... I choose to set the Tag of my first item to "First" in order to fire the trigger. (TabControl.Item[0].Tag = "First" after populating the TabControl)

```
<Style x:Key="styleTabItemMetro" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border Margin="0 4"
                                Name="borderBorder"
                                BorderBrush="#FF8C8E94" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" CornerRadius="0" />
                        <Grid Cursor="Hand" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              Margin="12,2"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Foreground}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="First">
                            <Setter TargetName="borderBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF9F9F9" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 1 0 0" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0" />
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"  Value="100" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushHeaderBackground}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```